# How to share image between Spring-Boot and React

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, rest, file

I am developing full stack internet-market and i need to send image to my Spring Rest Controller and save it to db. How to do that? I tryed something like that:

```
setFile(e.target.files && e.target.files[0])
```

This file is file from `<input type="file"/>`

After that i send this file to my put method

```
DishesService.addDish(dish, file)
```

```
static async addDish(dish: IDish, file: any) {
        try {
            await axios.post<IDish>('http://localhost:8080/dishes', dish)
                .then(response => {
                    this.updateDishImage(response.data.id, file)
                })
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('произошла ошибка при добавлении блюда')
        }
    }

    static async updateDishImage(id: number | undefined, image: any) {
        try {
            await axios.put('http://localhost:8080/dishes/' + id, {}, {
                params: {
                    file: image
                }
            })
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Произошла ошибка при добавлении картинки к блюду')
        }
    }
```

And my Spring Boot Put method:

```
    @PutMapping("{dishId}")
    public ResponseEntity<DishEntity> updateDishImage(@PathVariable Long dishId, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        DishEntity updateDish = dishService.updateDishImage(file, dishId);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(updateDish);
    }
```

I get exception:

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the headers:

```
headers: {
  "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
}
```

in your axios call

Comment: I got another exception: `Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
@RequestMapping(path = "{dishId}", method = PUT, consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity<DishEntity> updateDishImage(@PathVariable Long dishId, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
    // your logic
}
```

You can also encode you images into base64, then send them to the server-side as string.

Comment: Hello, i decided to encode in base64 and save as string. My question: what type of field image should be in db?

Comment: Hi, You can store it as string(varchar)